# Add views in a circle (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout, geometry, radial

I would like to add some views in a layout.

How can we put these views in relative or linear layout or any other layout in a circle same as in this image. I would like to do it using code.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can add a picture in the body of your question. I changed it for you.

Comment: Thank you PhaDaPhunk, in fact i don't have this fonctionnality because i'm a new user.

Comment: Oooh good to know. Thansk to you.

Comment: seems like this is something you would need to dynamically arrange, if you define a center of the circle as a specific point on your layout, couldn't you calculate positions on the circle where you would need to place each views x and y coordinates relative to the center?